# Compiling flex 4.0 app on flex 4.5/4.5.1 flex sdk

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, compilation, flash, flex4.5

Can someone give me a good page or resource where I can find info about compiling flex 4.0 sdk on flex 4.5/4.5.1 sdk.

I am having troubles. compilation goes well on 4.0 but whe I compile on 4.5 or 4.5.1 I get blank swf. What could be the problem?

Note: I have set flash player 10.2 for compilation and also as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc86a71867f5b4fa8351045f125dffc40d0-7fff.html

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Hero+Backwards+Compatability

Good luck :]